# How do I open a database file located in a specific folder in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, command-line-interface

I have this `chinook.db` database file that I have stored in C:\sqlite\db, and everytime I try accessing it using the sqlite shell by the command `.open C:\sqlite\db\chinook.db`, sqlite creates a `sqlitedbchinook.db` database file  in the home directory. Why is this happening and how do I resolve my issue ?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Command Line Shell For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html):

> ....You might want to use a full pathname to ensure that the file is in
> the directory that you think it is in. Use **forward-slashes** as the
> directory separator character. In other words use "c:/work/ex1.db",
> not "c:\work\ex1.db".

Change to:

```
.open "C:/sqlite/db/chinook.db"
```